# Do not trim mesh endpoints with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a mesh, some edges share verts, all verts are connected. Empties on the image below show the verts that belong to only 1 edge — mesh "endpoints":
[image]

I separate the edges, convert the mesh to a curve, trim it — every segment gets trimmed. However I want to offset only the points that aren't the endpoints from the previous image. Here's the result I'm getting with the empties showing where the 4 mesh endpoints should've stayed:
[image]

Here's my node tree:
[image]

I can get curve end points with the `Endpoint Selection` node but converting to curves will split the mesh into several splines. I've also tried to capture the mesh endpoints with the `Vertex Neighbours` node before splitting the mesh to get the 1-edge verts but... I don't know what to do with them after, there's no selection I could plug them into that I can think of.

And the scene:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfim0903q9pugla/trim_without_endpoints.blend?dl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this as follows:

[image]

- First determine the number of vertices per edge. You use this value as selection for `Set Position`.
- You determine the position by calculating the direction vector of an edge and scaling it with the value of your choice.
- The direction of the scaling is obtained by comparing the previously selected stand-alone point with the position of the points returned by the node `Edge Vertices`.

Of course, you can also turn this around by simply checking that the number of vertices equals $1$:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Beautiful! The solution was to make your own version of the trim with more control. Thank you!